# XSD Choice between two element

Tags: java, xsd, xsd-validation

I have four elements A, B, C, D. I wanted to create an XSD for which the schema should be the choice of [A & B & C] or [A & D].

```
<xs:schema xmlns:w3="http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/" 
       xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
       elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" version="1.0">

<xs:element name="abcd">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:choice>
            <xs:element name="A" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="B" type="xs:dateTime"/>
                <xs:element name="C" type="xs:decimal"/>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="D" type="xs:dateTime"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

is this right?
I generated java class from xsd via xjc.
I get this file:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
"a",
"b",
"c",
"d"
})
public class abcd {

@XmlElement(name = "a", required = true)
protected String a;
@XmlElement(name = "b")
protected String b;
@XmlElement(name = "c")
protected BigDecimal c;
@XmlElement(name = "d")
protected String d;
// get&set
}
```

this class does not match my xsd scheme.
what am i doing wrong?

Comment: First of all, what do you expect to have in your Java file? Do you have any requirements about the structure of your Java file?

Comment: Doesn't your schema allow [A] or [B&C] or [D] instead?

Comment: @Markus I can't find a mistake. I need [A & B & C] or [A & D]

Comment: @Alex Assuming that all elements are strings, the schema you have given accepts `<abcd><A/></abcd>` or `<abcd><D/></abcd>` (amongst other possible documents), but not `<abcd><A/><D/></abcd>`. Is this what you had in mind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Markus is correct. Your schema accepts a choice of either [A], [B & C], or [D].

An alternative way to think about `[A & B & C] or [A & D]` is `[A] followed by either [B & C] or [D]`. This can be represented in XSD by moving the A element out of the choice into a sequence, so something like this:

```xml
<xs:element name="abcd">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="A" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:choice>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="B" type="xs:dateTime"/>
                    <xs:element name="C" type="xs:decimal"/>
                </xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="D" type="xs:dateTime"/>
            </xs:choice>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```